# How to integrate account-js package to already existed mongo db?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a meteor app and want to migrate non-meteor app. I found account-js is compatible with the meteor account system. When I create new user everything works well but If I want to login with already existed user account-js methods does not work and I get unauth message everytime. How to login with already existed users by using account-js ?

```
   
const accountsPassword = new AccountsPassword({
  verifyPassword: (plainPassword, storedPassword) => {
    const hashedPassword = crypto.Hash('sha256').update(plainPassword).digest('hex')

    console.log('*****Verify Password*****')
    return bcrypt.compareSync(plainPassword, storedPassword)
  }
})

const accountsServer = new AccountsServer(
  {
    db: accountsMongo
  },
  {
    password: accountsPassword
  }
)

const accountsGraphQL = AccountsModule.forRoot({ accountsServer })


const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: mergeTypeDefs([typeDefs, accountsGraphQL.typeDefs]),
  resolvers: mergeResolvers([resolvers, accountsGraphQL.resolvers]),
  schemaDirectives: {
    ...accountsGraphQL.schemaDirectives
  }
})

const schemaMiddleware = applyMiddleware(schema, permissions)
```

Comment: how does accounts-js hash it's passwords? The way you are showing it in your code, using hex encoded sha256 hashes? If so, then that's not going to work. If you look at the hashed passwords created by meteor's accounts-password, they are not even hex, e.g.,  `"services" : { "password" : {"bcrypt" : $2b$10$L6HP23tUgsYuQ0LVwPXw1eODKLyDPvvxXo1IjZEx6.PBxfOeQHqS."}..`

Comment: You may be right but the actual problem is that "verifyPassword" method does not triggered by anything when I login with user which is already existed in db. If I create a new user, "verifyPassword" method is triggered and works well. If I achieve to trigger verify method when I try to login with already existed user in db, I can test hash mechanism but I could not achieve yet. Thank you for your comment btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accounts-js utilizes an entirely different authentication mechanism than Meteor authentication system. accounts-js uses JWT tokens while Meteor uses unique hashes so it's not cross-compatible. I wrote a blog post about it which you can read [here](https://unchained.shop/en/blog/meteoraccountsmigration)